# Collections.shuffle repeat same item in android

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, shuffle

I have a very strange problem, I have ArrayList of 2 objects, when I run Collections.shuffle on it , the returned list sometimes comes with only one of the two objects repeated two times

Can anyone help me ?

**EDIT**

My Class

```
public class AdUnitResponse implements Serializable{

    private int                     mBannerId;
    private int                     mAppId;
    private int                     mRegionId;
    private boolean                 mIsEnabled;
    private String                  mStartDate;
    private String                  mEndDate;
    private AdBannerType            mBannerType;
    private String                  mSubType;
    private int                     mDisplayOrder;
    private String                  mIdentifierType;
    private int                     mIdentifierId;
    private String                  mSmallImageAr;
    private String                  mSmallImageEn;
    private String                  mLargeImageAr;
    private String                  mLargeImageEn;
    private String                  mVideo;
    private String                  mTitleAr;
    private String                  mTitleEn;
    private String                  mPhone;
    private String                  mTargetUrl;
    private boolean                 mIsOpenTargetUrl;
    }
```

then I fill it with data come from json request 
and use this method to shuffle them before return them

```
public ArrayList<AdUnitResponse> getRelatedAds() {


    if (mRelatedAds != null && mRelatedAds.size() > 1) {
        Collections.shuffle(mRelatedAds);
    }

    return mRelatedAds;
}
```

then use the returned list to add view with image for each item in the list in linear layout

sometimes one item appear two times

Comment: can you give an example code - so that it is possible to reproduce your problem

Comment: ok will edit the post

Comment: in general `Collections.shuffle` does manipulate the original list and `void` is returned.

Comment: @KevinWallis please check my edit

Comment: have you debugged and checked the json maybe there is something wrong because the shuffle code is correct - maybe you are manipulating the list from somewhere in your code.